# MSSQL Management Studio 2014 not showing the "Tasks>Restore>Database..." Dialog

Tags: sql-server-2014

When right clicking on a database in the Object Explorer panel of SQL Server Management Studio 2014, and then expanding to "Tasks>Restore>Database...", then selecting it, the database restore dialog does not appear.

Please note that:
1 - I was using this before and then it stopped working
2 - It works on some other databases!
3 - Restarting Management Studio or even rebooting the client machine (Windows 7) does not solve the problem.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Have permissions on the database itself changed?  (Wild guess.)

Comment: Nothing has changed...

Comment: Can you try to "restore" the SSMS window or if you have multiple monitors, move it to another monitor and try again?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.
SQL server studio 2014 doesn't like error "Unable to create a restore plan due to break in the LSN chain". And fails to open restore dialog.
Fix LSN chain by issuing FULL backup.
After that restore dialog should work.